# Weather apps that report snow accumulation

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation, ios-appstore

Are there any weather apps for iOS that report the amount of *snow accumulation*, not just precipitation? Something like *"3-5 inches of snow is expected*".

I've tried the stock weather app and several others. All I seem to get is whether or not it will snow and the amount of precipitation which is merely a fraction of actual snow accumulation. Ideally I'd also like to know if ground/road conditions are expected to be icy.

Comment: I just want to say - in mountainous areas, accumulation and road conditions vary widely. Is causes some data sources and models to be really vague. What are of the world do you require the app to be well sourced with weather forecast data?

Comment: Usually this info is available in a local weather forecast on tv and radio and tends to be fairly accurate. I suppose I'm looking for the same info in an app.

Comment: Just keep in mind to make your question broadly applicable - without specifying location, anyone's recommendation becomes a) a crapshoot b) presumed USA centric. Some suggestions for asking a software recommendation are collected at http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

[Dark Sky](http://darkskyapp.com) shows expected accumulation... In my experience it is pretty inaccurate, but it tries. It has almost always forecasted more accumulation than actually accumulates. It is pretty accurate with its other predictions though.

The prediction engine that runs Dark Sky is available at http://forecast.io if you want to try it out for free. I can't remember for sure if it shows expected accumulation, but I think it does.